# Issues Adding reCAPTCHA to PHP Form

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I recently built a contact form in PHP, but I'd like to add a captcha, however I'm a little lost. I've done some searching, and it seams as though Google's reCAPTCHA is the best option.

I've tried appending the code from [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024), but the submit button doesn't seem to be connected. I believe it's a syntax issue, but I'm not a PHP pro.

PHP:

```
<?php

// Load reCAPTCHA library
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$emailFrom = $email;
$emailTo = "mario@mtscollective.com";
$subject = "API Website Contact Request";

// Prepare email body text
$body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br /> <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br /> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
}


$secret = "xxx";
$response = null;
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// If submitted, check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}


// Send email 
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

// Redirect to success or error pages
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=thankyou.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
        <label for="name"><span>Name</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your name." /></label>
        <label for="email"><span>Email</span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your email address." /></label>
        <label for="message"><span>Message</span><textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your message."></textarea></label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcBawsTAAAAAKBPfGs1jApXNRLvR2MIPng0Fxol"></div>
        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="" class="submit-button" /></label>                  
    </form>             
</div>
```

Any help or advice would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Show your form html too.

Comment: Is your form being posted? As in, is `$_POST['g-captcha-response']` set?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I don't have much PHP experience. Do you mean am I getting a response?

Comment: Yes, do you get the stuff being printed?

Comment: you do nothing wt the actual captcha check result : `$response`

Comment: I don't think it is. For a split second, I see this before it loads thankyou.html: http://i.imgur.com/VubvjuM.jpg. If it helps, I'm testing this on http://api.marioparra.me. Thanks.

Comment: the result if the check from google is inside `$response` you don't check it, so even if google thinks they are a spammer you send the email anwyay

Comment: I see, but I'm just unsure how to check the response in my current script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly dump recaptcha version 1 start using version 2

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

once installed:

```
<?php

// Load reCAPTCHA library
include_once ("YOURPATH/reCAPTCHA/autoload.php");

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$emailFrom = $email;
$emailTo = "mario@mtscollective.com";
$subject = "API Website Contact Request";

// Prepare email body text
$body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br /> <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br /> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

/*
 * foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
 * echo '<p><strong>' . $key . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';
 * }
 */


$secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($resp->isSuccess()){
    $success = mail($emailTo,$subject,$body,$headers);
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'thankyou.html');
}else{
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'error.html');
}


?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was using 2. What does autoload.php refer to? Do I just need to reference `<script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`? Ah, I think I see what you've done. My original if statement wasn't checking the response, right?

Comment: both those questions are answerable at the link provided above.

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Class 'ReCaptcha' not found in /home/ourcore/public_html/_clients/api/contact-form.php on line 21`

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't included the ReCaptcha folder. Got it working—thanks! Next step will be to display the success messages inline instead of on separate pages.

Comment: just replace the header call with echo what ever

Comment: Yeah, but they get printed on a separate page, not within the form. Should I echo the messages within index.html instead?